# Unable to convert cython generated C language code to executable file

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

I am using windows operating system. I have visual studio and all the build tools associated with it. I have simple python script. I used cython to generate a "C" file. I am trying to convert this C file to an executable. I do not want to use any other modules like pyinstaller, py2exe or cxFreeze.

The conversion from .py to C was successful. However sadly I am getting some errors while converting this C file to an executable.

Could anyone please help me ? I have checked various other questions on this issue and none of have them have this issue.

**This is my (.pyx script)**

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

**I used this following command in CMD to build a C extension for this script:**

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace -DMS_WIN64
```

**Then I am using this command in CMD to build an executable:**

```
gcc -DMS_WIN64 C:/Users/Siva/Desktop/Scripts/TEST/test.c -IC:/"Program Files"/Python37/include -LC:/"Program Files"/Python37/libs -lpython37 -o output
```

**This produces the following error:**

```
C:\Users\Siva\Desktop\Scripts\TEST>gcc -DMS_WIN64 C:/Users/Siva/Desktop/Scripts/TEST/test.c -IC:/"Program Files"/Python37/include -LC:/"Program Files"/Python37/libs -lpython37.a -o output
C:/Users/Siva/Desktop/Scripts/TEST/test.c:213:41: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
     enum { __pyx_check_sizeof_voidp = 1 / (int)(SIZEOF_VOID_P == sizeof(void*)) };
                                         ^
C:/Users/Siva/Desktop/Scripts/TEST/test.c:213:12: error: enumerator value for '__pyx_check_sizeof_voidp' is not an integer constant
     enum { __pyx_check_sizeof_voidp = 1 / (int)(SIZEOF_VOID_P == sizeof(void*)) };
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**I have attached a screenshot of the error below**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlxLf.png)

Comment: I don't know how it relates to cython, but in Python 3.x, division returns a float. i.e. `>>> 1 / 1` outputs `1.0`. It's called "true division" in [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). Python 2.x has "classic division".

Comment: See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2734

Comment: I added that flag -DMS_WIN64 to my code and checked. The issue still persists. I have edited that in my question too. The other solution they had provided there was to use gendef ../vcruntime140.def command. When I do that it says *** [vcruntime140.def] failed to open(). Please guide me here

Comment: looks like a compile time check that fails. One can expect SIZEOF_VOID_P to match sizeof(void*), thus the result should be one, but here it fails.... to me the code is just trying to communicate with you that there is something wrong hapening. are you sure you are not messing 32/64 bits somewhere?

Comment: My python says its "Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".                                                                                                                      My GCC version says its "gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0" and My OS is 64 bit. Could you tell me the other places where I could check ?

Comment: Side-note: Make sure you use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard for your main script; there are a number of problems caused by failing to do so (e.g. with any script that uses `multiprocessing`, among other causes).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally After a long eternal struggle I have found the solution. Thanks to Joshua for the great support.

There is a small modification in the .PYX code. It appears like we must define everything within a function so that when the code gets converted to C language, it has a main function in it.

**So the first step is the .PYX is edited as:**

```
from tkinter import Tk

cdef public void function():
    root = Tk()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
```

**Then I used the following command to generate the header file (.h) and the C program file**

```
python -m cython test.pyx --embed
```

**This is the trick:**

**Go to the C program file that was generated and search for the wmain function and remove the "w" from it. Or you could just Ctrl + F search for wmain and replace its instances with main.**

**For exmaple in my program there was only one wmain instance. I changed it to main. It look something like the code shown below. Just change the wmain to main.**

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
#elif defined(WIN32) || defined(MS_WINDOWS)
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
```

**Then I used the GCC command to generate the executable. The command is as follows. I do not understand why it works. But it does.**

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-8.1.0 -mconsole -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -DMS_WIN64 C:/Users/Siva/Desktop/Scripts/CYTHON/test.c -IC:/"Program Files"/Python37/include -LC:/"Program Files"/Python37/libs -lpython37 -o output
```

I only wish someone would explain why approach works.

Answer (score 3):

Environmental check failed; probably autodetect is broken. Try one of the following to override it:

```
gcc -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -DMS_WIN64 ...

gcc -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=4 ...
```

Where the `8` constant is for 64 bit output and the `4` constant is for 32 bit output. It's most likely that you configured for 64 bit and actually invoked the 32 bit gcc. If so, the following invocation should work assuming the 64 bit targeting `gcc` is also installed.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DSIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -DMS_WIN64 ...
```

Comment: Perfect this clears the SIZE_OF_VOIDP error. However, now it says:       C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @SwaroopMajipatti: Maybe you need `-mconsole` but I'm about to run out of experience.

Comment: It has also failed. I added mconsole, mwindows , everything has failed. Anyway thanks for helping this much. I will keep exploring.

Comment: @SwaroopMajipatti: The last resort is to define a `WinMain` that calls `main`.

Comment: Where exactly would I do that ? how ? is there any example where you could direct me ?

Comment: @SwaroopMajipatti: Making `main()` from `WinMain()` is actually a pretty good question of its own right.

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with C programming. Okay, anyway, I will explore and check it out. By the way, the C code I have does not contain a main() function.

Comment: @SwaroopMajipatti: Oh. That's your actual problem then. No main no program.

Comment: The thing is that entire C program looks like a C++ header file. I am unable to get my head around where to add the main function.